# Clear Applcation Cache with Event Domain DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-handling

I want to clear my application cache after updating an element of my domain.

In that case I raise an event NodeEndPointReferenceChangedEvent from my Domain Layer.

The cache in managed in Services Layer.

I'm not sure where I place the NodeEndPointReferenceChangedHandler who will be responsible for catching the event and invoking the service to clear the cache.

It's ok if I divide the Handles in two layer:
DomainHandles who will handle events at the Domain level
ServiceHandles who will handle events at the application layer (cache services)

The other point is when the event will be rase? In the case of clear cache I prefer raise the event after the commit of transaction. But in other case or in the Domain Handler i prefer manage the event in the same transaction.
So I can define two different interface for manage this case (for example ITransactionNotification and ICommitedTransactionNotification) and the infrastraction layer (in my case EF Core because I use .Net Core) will raise the events pre or post transaction.

Comment: The point of events is that anyone can react to them, be it a domain or application layer. It does not matter. The domain does not care.

Comment: Ok, so i can create a subscriber (Handler) in my DomainLayer and another in ServierLayer.
But if i want to raise an event inside the domain transaction and another one after the transaction commit, I can publish two event (Event Domain for the transaction and Event Public for action to do after transaction?)